# Redirect stdout and stderr after redirection command

Tags: bash, redirect

In a bash script I am enabling IP forwarding using the following command:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

However I also want to include my own error messages so I have to redirect the stdout and stderr to `/dev/null`, which looks like the following:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward >/dev/null 2>&1`

This works for commands that do not have the redirection symbol in it, for example:

`route add default gw 10.8.0.1 > /dev/null 2>&1`

Is there any way I can make this work for commands that do have a redirection in them? Is there a workaround for this? Any other way I can do this better?

Comment: It's not clear what problem you are trying to solve. You can only have one redirection per file descriptor on a command.

Comment: I want to execute `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and if this goes wrong, I want the stderr and stdout (error message and output) to be redirected to /dev/null. In other words, I don't want any message when an error occurs.

Comment: You don't have to redirect standard output again; it's already going to `/proc/...` You only need `echo 1 > /proc/... 2> /dev/null`.

Comment: Of course! That makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your redirections are nonsensical (no offense).

This:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward >/dev/null 2>&1
```

will:

1. redirect `echo`'s standard output to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`;
2. redirect `echo`'s standard output to `/dev/null`
3. redirect `echo`'s standard error to where file descriptor `1` points, i.e., to `/dev/null`.

Hence, globally, redirection 2 cancels redirection 1: nothing is going to go to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`!

I guess you want to redirect `echo`'s standard output to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` and `echo`'s standard error to `/dev/null`. This is achieved by:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 2>/dev/null
```

But read on, I believe that's not the answer you're looking for!

---

Why do you want to redirect `echo`'s standard error to `/dev/null`?
`echo` very rarely writes to standard error. In fact, the only time `echo` will write to standard error is when there's a write error. There are a couple of ways this could happen:

- if the disk is full (that can be simulated with `/dev/full`):

  ```
  $ echo hello >/dev/full
  bash: echo: write error: No space left on device
  $ echo hello >/dev/full 2>/dev/null
  $
  ```

  (no error messages shown with the redirection `2>/dev/null`).
- if `echo`'s standard out is closed:

  ```
  $ ( exec >&-; echo hello )
  bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor
  $ ( exec >&-; echo hello 2> /dev/null )
  $
  ```

  (no error messages shown with the redirection `2>/dev/null`).

There might be other cases where `echo` outputs to standard error. But the following are certainly not among them:

- Redirecting `echo`'s standard output to a non-existent file descriptor:

  ```
  $ echo hello >&42
  bash: 42: Bad file descriptor
  $ echo hello >&42 2>/dev/null
  bash: 42: Bad file descriptor
  $
  ```

  The redirection `2>/dev/null` doesn't fix anything; you can actually see that the error comes from `bash` and not from `echo` (the latter would have `bash: echo:` as a prefix).
- Redirecting `echo`'s standard output to a file without write permission:

  ```
  $ touch testfile
  $ chmod -w testfile
  $ echo hello > testfile
  bash: testfile: Permission denied
  $ echo hello > testfile 2>/dev/null
  bash: testfile: Permission denied
  $
  ```

  Same as above, the redirection `2>/dev/null` doesn't fix anything.

The previous cases are not fixed by `2>/dev/null`, since the error occurs at Bash's level, before the command is even executed and the redirections performed, because it's at the moment of the redirection that Bash encounters an error: it can't open the stream for writing and outputs the error message to standard output.<sup>†</sup>

Now I guess you're trying to fix the following scenario: when the user doesn't have enough rights to write to `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`:

```
$ echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Permission denied
$
```

The error message on standard error can't be redirected with a simple redirection<sup>‡</sup>:

```
$ echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward 2>/dev/null
bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: Permission denied
$
```

A standard way to redirect the error that occurs at the redirection level (i.e., *before* the command is even executed) is to use groupings:

```
$ { echo 1 >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward; } 2>/dev/null
```

Now that explains why the solution you posted as an answer works: let's go through it and we'll see that there's something that shows you didn't completely understand redirections (and hopefully this post will help you understanding a few things); your code is:

```
function ip_forward
{
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
}
ip_forward >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will run the function `ip_forward`, and redirect:

1. its standard output to `/dev/null`;
2. and then its standard error to where its standard output points (i.e., to `/dev/null`).

But the function `ip_forward` doesn't output anything to standard output! so the redirection `>/dev/null` is *only* useful for the `2>&1` part of the redirection. In fact, your code is completely equivalent to:

```
function ip_forward
{
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
}
ip_forward 2>/dev/null
```

But then (since you only use a function construct as a way to achieve what you wanted—not because you want a function), it's much better to write your code as either:

```
echo 1 2>/dev/null >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or

```
{ echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward; } 2>/dev/null
```

(the latter being preferred).

Sorry for this long post!

---

<sup>†</sup>
There's something we should be aware of: the order of redirection. They are performed from left to right, as Bash reads them. How about we first redirect standard error, and then standard output to a non-existent/non-writable stream?

```
$ echo hello 2>/dev/null >&42
$
```

That's right, it works.

<sup>‡</sup>
Well, *can,* if you understood the previous footnote:

```
$ echo 1 2>/dev/null >/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
$ echo $?
1
$
```

No error on standard error! that's because of the order of the redirections.

Comment: @Stan: As I said, `echo` rarely writes to standard output… do you really have a scenario where the `2>/dev/null` as you wrote it (i.e., as the last redirection) is useful? I would: either not redirect standard error at all, or redirect _all_ of standard error as I shown in this answer (using groups, or redirecting standard error _first_).

Comment: Rarely writes to standard **output**? And no, I have no specific scenario to be honest, since I'm not that experienced with bash I just wanted to handly any error "just in case".

Comment: Ah, then I understand. Thanks for your input, I learned something today! :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward ip_forward 2>/dev/null`

`echo 1` is the stdout part so this does not have to be redirected anymore. I only had to redirect stderr by adding `2>/dev/null`.

Comment: Not solved. `ip_forward` already redirects its standard output, so it produces no output. What you have done is no different from `echo 1 > .../ip_forward 2>/dev/null`

Comment: You might be correct about the first part. But using a function the 1 actually gets echoed to `.../ip_forward`. When using `echo 1 > .../ip_forward 2>/dev/null 2>&1` my `.../ip_forward` file stays at 0. So that does work now. I'm not sure if it correctly redirects stdout and stderr though.